# How can I syntax highlight a single text input field?

Tags: javascript, html, input, token, syntax-highlighting

How can I best syntax highlight a single text area, with extremely simple highlighting rules?

Javascript-based code editors are huge and bloated - I don't want multi-line editing, line numbers, or anything like that. Just something simple that parses inputted text and allows formatting on it.

For example, if the user is creating a message template and has tokens available called `firstName` and `lastName`, and there is an HTML single-line input field available, if they type:

```
Hello, {{firstName}} {{lastName}}!
```

What would be the best method to apply styling (colors, borders, etc) to the well-defined tokens, while still allowing the user to edit the entire string of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have a function that I created that highlight words when it is inside `[...]`, I made an adjustment for you and then it gets what is inside `{{...}}`.

But the problem is that, you can't set HTML in an input field, so you can't highlight words in a simple way inside inputs or textareas, you need to add the highlited text to another kind of element.

A possible solution to that, would be to have a `div` with `contentEditable=true`, so maybe it will be easier to type and highlight in the same input.

Look the below code (where I made based on a simple input, not contentEditable div) if it is what you are looking for.

```js
function setHighlight(input){  
  let newText = Highlight(input.value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = newText;
}

function Highlight(text){
  var htmlText = text;
  var attrs = htmlText.match(/\{{(.*?)\}}/g);

  if (attrs != null) {
      var stringAttrs = attrs.join(" ")
      attrs = stringAttrs.replace(/}}/g, '').replace(/\{{/g, '').split(" ");
      for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
          var attr = attrs[i];
          if (attr.length > 0) {
              attr = "{{" + attr + "}}";
              if (htmlText.indexOf(attr) > -1) {                  
                  htmlText = htmlText.replace(attr, "<span class='highlight'>" + attr + "</span>");
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return htmlText;
}
```

```css
input{
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
}

.highlight{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #14e;
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" oninput="setHighlight(this)" value="type a {{token}} here">

<div id="result"></div>
```

And here, I did with a contentEditable, it seems more what are you looking for:

```js
function setHighlight(inputSpan){  
  let newText = Highlight(inputSpan.textContent);
  inputSpan.innerHTML = newText;
  setCaretToEnd(inputSpan);
}

function Highlight(text){
  var htmlText = text;
  var attrs = htmlText.match(/\{{(.*?)\}}/g);

  if (attrs != null) {
      var stringAttrs = attrs.join(" ")
      attrs = stringAttrs.replace(/}}/g, '').replace(/\{{/g, '').split(" ");
      for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
          var attr = attrs[i];
          if (attr.length > 0) {
              attr = "{{" + attr + "}}";
              if (htmlText.indexOf(attr) > -1) {                  
                  htmlText = htmlText.replace(attr, "<span class='highlight'>" + attr + "</span>");
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return htmlText;
}

function setCaretToEnd(elem){
  let range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(elem);
  range.collapse(false);
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
#txt{
  width: 320px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #222;
}

.highlight{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #14e;
}
```

```html
<span id="txt" contentEditable="true" oninput="setHighlight(this)">type a {{token}} here</span>
```

Comment: I was hoping someone had written some type of library for this, but after much searching, I didn't find anything. Still, this is a really good start, and the `contentEditable` suggestion is a good idea. I'll try and take your sample and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your suggestions!